# realtime database: next N events

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have a model for `events`. Events all have a start time

```
orgs: { 
 "$org": { 
    events:
      "$event_key": { 
         ...
         details: {
            start
```

I want to fetch the next 3 upcoming events:

i.e get all events that have a details.start > now, sorted asc, limit 3

I *thought* I could write something like this:

```
firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/orgs/foo')
    .orderByChild('details/start')
    .startAt(Date.now())
    .limitToFirst(5)
    .once('value', x => console.log(x.val()))
```

But I currently get an empty value. Is this the right approach? I am not 100% sure that I am using orderByChild correctly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oi. Forgot `events`. This did the trick:

```
firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/orgs/foo/events')
    .orderByChild('details/start')
    .startAt(Date.now())
    .limitToFirst(3)
    .once('value', (snap) => snap.forEach((child) => console.log(child.val().details.start)));
```